# How to store dataset with protobuf

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, data-stream

I need to store flexible data sets compactly and with ability to streaming.
Data set contain tabular data, each rows contain same types.

Whats better:
 - write one big proto-message with repeated proto-messages?
 - multiple proto messages writes directly to steram (with some additional info, about proto format inside)?
 - or some better way exists?

Is protobuf support streaming?

Comment: Hi I have the same need to send Dataset objects and receive also Dataset. Did you find a way with gRPC? Thanks

Comment: @VAAA we are added paging compatability to structure.

Comment: Is there a way I can see a sample on how are you using gRPC with .NET Dataset type? Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

As you've probably noticed, protobuf is mostly a framework for serializing/deserializing data into/from a binary form. If you're looking to transfer that data, you can of course send it in a streaming way - it's just bytes after all.

You could write your own network protocol, but probably what you're looking for is something like [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/csharp.html) (Link is to the C# tutorial - deduced from your tags). gRPC allows for streaming - you can learn more about it [here](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#server-streaming-rpc). Quick quote:

> Server streaming RPC A server-streaming RPC is similar to our simple
>   example, except the server sends back a stream of responses after
>   getting the client’s request message. After sending back all its
>   responses, the server’s status details (status code and optional
>   status message) and optional trailing metadata are sent back to
>   complete on the server side. The client completes once it has all the
>   server’s responses.
>
> Client streaming RPC A client-streaming RPC is also similar to our
>   simple example, except the client sends a stream of requests to the
>   server instead of a single request. The server sends back a single
>   response, typically but not necessarily after it has received all the
>   client’s requests, along with its status details and optional trailing
>   metadata.

Also, for a quick example, visit [this page](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/csharp.html#server-side-streaming-rpc). An example from gRPC's website:

```
public override async Task<RouteSummary> RecordRoute(Grpc.Core.IAsyncStreamReader<Point> requestStream,
    Grpc.Core.ServerCallContext context)
{
    int pointCount = 0;
    int featureCount = 0;
    int distance = 0;
    Point previous = null;
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (await requestStream.MoveNext())
    {
        var point = requestStream.Current;
        pointCount++;
        if (CheckFeature(point).Exists())
        {
            featureCount++;
        }
        if (previous != null)
        {
            distance += (int) previous.GetDistance(point);
        }
        previous = point;
    }

    stopwatch.Stop();

    return new RouteSummary
    {
        PointCount = pointCount,
        FeatureCount = featureCount,
        Distance = distance,
        ElapsedTime = (int)(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000)
    };
}
```

**EDIT**

Example proto file with gRPC definitions in it.

```
syntax = "proto3";

message DataRow {
    // Your data row here
}

message SendDataResponse {
}

service DataAcceptor {
  // Send multiple rows in a streaming scenario
  rpc SendData (stream DataRow) returns (SendDataResponse) {}
}
```

Comment: The site is good I just read it but when sending for example an un typed Dataset there is no need to declare anything right? Because is just a stream isn’t?